# ubuntu 16.04: nautilus ignores keys in dconf and gsettings

Tags: nautilus, dconf, gsettings

****** **UPDATE - now fixed, see below** ******

There is a mismatch between the preferences accessed via the nautilus menu and the values seen by dconf or gsettings.

From the terminal I get:

$ gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-hidden-files

**true**

$ dconf read /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-hidden-files

**true**

Same values opening dconf-editor. But if I go via the menu:

Edit->Preferences->Views->'Show hidden and backup files' the key is **unchecked**

The actual behaviour of nautilus follows the menu preference: dconf is ignored.

On top of that, I can't make the menu preference stick: each time I set 'Show hidden and backup files' via the menu, it only lasts for the current session: after a reboot it is back to unchecked. 
Maybe the two things are independent, but I thought I'd mention them both here in case it helps.

****** **UPDATE:** ******

Well, I feel dumb! The answer is simple: I was looking at the wrong key. I've noticed that the description of *org.gnome.nautilus.preferences.show-hidden-files* in dconf-editor says:

*This key is deprecated and ignored. The "show-hidden" key from "org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser" is now used instead.*

So that's the key to change, and it works.

As for the settings being reset every time I reboot, that is still happening, so I've opened a separate question here:

[nautilus preferences lost after every reboot, ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165731/nautilus-preferences-lost-after-every-reboot-ubuntu-16-04)