# nautilus preferences lost after every reboot, ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, preferences

Nautilus doesn't seem to save changes to the default preferences in a permanent way. This is happening for **'show hidden and backup files'** in the Views tab.

It starts as unchecked, then if I check it, it sticks after a logout and login, but is back to unchecked after a shutdown.

What could be happening?

---

@steeldriver, yes: *~/.config/dconf/user* is owned by me and permissions are *'-rw-rw-r--'*. If I change *'show hidden and backup files'* the *'last modified'* date changes, so I'd say it gets updated. Something must be overwriting it with the default on shutdown or boot. I'm working now so I can't reboot now to verify that the date changes, I'll check next time I do.

---

update: *~/.config/dconf/user* gets modified every time I login (and reboot, clearly).

---

update: I've noticed that *'show hidden and backup files'* isn't always lost between reboots: **sometimes it reverts to unchecked, and sometimes it stays checked**, but I can't see any pattern, it seems random.

Comment: Is `~/.config/dconf/user` owned and writeable by you?

Comment: @steeldriver: yes, the permissions are -rw-rw-r-- (HOW DO I PUT A LINE BREAK HERE??)<br/>  
BTW: problem not fixed, it still happens